# Stored procedured doesnt give the result back

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have written such a stored procedure, it must return a result, but it doesnt do that. it returns only a message that stored procedure runs successfully.

How should I change my SP?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestTVP 
(
@param1 int, 
@param2 int,
@a int OUTPUT
)
as
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
  DECLARE @T1 as TABLE
 (
   PK INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   Wert INTEGER,
   Name INTEGER
 )
 INSERT INTO @T1(Wert,Name) VALUES (@param1,@param2) 
 return select count(*) from @T1

 GO


exec TestTVP '1','22'
```

Comment: You're not capturing the `RETURN`'d result. Are you sure you want to RETURN it rather than just SELECT?

Comment: Don't what you want to achieve with this SP, but if you are interested in the result, you have to use an OUTPUT parameter or you might think about a Stored Funciton or a VIEW. This depends on your goals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass `OUTPUT` parameter

```
declare @z int
exec TestTVP '1','22' ,@z output
```

and remove `return` from Stored Procedure make it only

```
...
select count(*) from @T1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use out parameter if you want the output :

```
DECLARE @Z int
EXEC TestTVP '2', '22',@z out
```